# Convert TWIML (Gather and Dial) to use API and VOIP

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm currently looking at a basic example of create call https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#create-a-call-resource.

The TWIML fetched in the url parameter uses the <Gather> verb to call a number via the action attribute then <Say> something on a loop.  Once the DTMF input is detected it dials a second number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="dtmf" action="/dial/john" method="POST">
        <Say loop="0">Press a key to connect to John</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

response at /dial/john:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Now, my question is would it be possible to use the API to do the exact same and reduce costs?  The cost per minute for each call is GBP0.0175 whereas I believe it could be lower using the API / SIP / VOIP?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  you can tell Twilio you want to connect to a PSTN phone [<Number>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number), a [<Sip>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip) endpoint, a [<Client>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/twiml) ID or even a Twilio Programmable Wireless [<Sim>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sim) card.

Depending on which if these you use they will have different costs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin, thanks for the reply.  So you're saying that there's no need to use the API?

Comment: Hi @devinrader, thanks for the reply.  So you're saying that there's no need to use the API we can carry on with the above code and still reduce costs?

If I form TWIML like 
    <Response>
        <Dial>
            <Number>
                415-123-4567
            </Number>
        </Dial>
    </Response>

then we could reduce cost but only if 415-123-4567 is a SIP endpoint.  I'm not sure it would work in our situation because 415-123-4567 is a landline / local number.

Comment: Your app has two call legs, the inbound and outbound. There is a cost associated with each of those, but that specific cost depends on the product.  This FQ article does a good job explaining this: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-